# How to convert javascript regex to php regex

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I want to convert this javascript regex to php regex. I have test the code can run.

```
<img.*?src='(?!http[s]*:\/\/img.[a-zA-Z0-9]*.test\/)(.*?)'

<img alt='' src='http://img.dev.teeeest/images/UID' />
<img alt='' src='https://img.deaaav.test.com/images/UID/' />
<img alt='' src='http://api.com/images/UID' />
<img alt='' src='http://img.deaSassav.test/images/UID' />
<img alt='' src='https://img.dev.test/images/UID' />
```

It will choose first three of these. I want php regex will have the same result.

```
$body = "<img alt='' src='http://img.dev.teeeest/images/UID' />
<img alt='' src='https://img.deaaav.test.com/images/UID.ux/' />
<img alt='' src='http://api.com/images/UID' />
<img alt='' src='http://img.deaSassav.test/images/UID' />
<img alt='' src='https://img.dev.test/images/UID' />";
$body = stripslashes($body);
$img_array = array();
preg_match_all('/<img[^>]*?src=[\'|\"](http[s]*:\/\/img.[a-zA-Z0-9]*.test\/[^"|^\']*?)[\'|\"][^>]*?>/isU', $body, $img_array);
$img_array = array_unique($img_array[1]);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($img_array);
echo "</pre>";
```

i use the website test https://regex101.com/
i attempt use add an ^ before http[s]. like this

```
<img[^>]*?src=[\'|\"](^http[s]*:\/\/img.[a-zA-Z0-9]*.test\/)[^"|^\']*?[\'|\"][^>]*?>
```

i want to negative what have this

```
http[s]*:\/\/img.[a-zA-Z0-9]*.test\/
```

Comment: i just don't know how to write it... i try a lot function. but do't have the same result

Comment: Can you include the functions you said you tried, but did not get the correct result with?

Comment: it is my first question on stackoverflow. maybe have some false expression sorry

Comment: It is clear to understand what you are wanting to do, however, it is hard to assist you if you do not include your attempts.

Comment: <img[^>]*?src=[\'|\"](http[s]*:\/\/img.[a-zA-Z0-9]*.ux\/)[^"|^\']*?[\'|\"][^>]*?>
this is my php regex. it can choose the last two. but i want the others

Comment: Always think about the problem thoroughly and constructively before posting. Do you think this kind of conversion is logical, possible or beneficial?

Comment: Please add the above to your question. Also include some more php, so we can run the code.

Comment: ok i edit. sorry

Comment: the php code can run. but can't get what i want result. i think just lack some expression. but don't know how to write

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your javascript regex works fine; you just need to change the `s` flag to `m`:

```
$body = "<img alt='' src='http://img.dev.teeeest/images/UID' />
<img alt='' src='https://img.deaaav.test.com/images/UID.ux/' />
<img alt='' src='http://api.com/images/UID' />
<img alt='' src='http://img.deaSassav.test/images/UID' />
<img alt='' src='https://img.dev.test/images/UID' />";
$body = stripslashes($body);
$img_array = array();
preg_match_all("/<img.*?src='(?!http[s]*:\/\/img.[a-zA-Z0-9]*.test\/)(.*?)/imU", $body, $img_array);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($img_array[0]);
echo "</pre>";
```

Output:

```
<pre>Array
(
    [0] => <img alt='' src='http://img.dev.teeeest/images/UID' />
    [1] => <img alt='' src='https://img.deaaav.test.com/images/UID.ux/' />
    [2] => <img alt='' src='http://api.com/images/UID' />
)
</pre>
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/Uffb5)

Comment: It doesn't work on php, but thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Night i've given you a working demo in PHP. What do you mean, it doesn't work?

Comment: @Night if you want exactly the same output as the other answer, just change `$img_array[0]` to `$img_array[1]` https://3v4l.org/ppRKp

Comment: yes...i just try it. it is on $img_array[1] thank you

Answer (score 0):

This expression might also work:

```
<img\b.*?\bsrc=['"](?!https?:\/\/img\.[a-z0-9]*\.test\/)([^'"]*)
```

---

> If you wish to explore/simplify/modify the expression, it's been
>   explained on the top right panel of
>   [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/4iWaCr/1). If you'd like, you
>   can also watch in [this
>   link](https://regex101.com/r/4iWaCr/1/debugger), how it would match
>   against some sample inputs.

---